# How do you access the ArrayList attribute of an object when that object is also in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, attributes

So I have several objects in an ArrayList. Each of these objects have an attribute that is several Strings in an ArrayList. I'm trying to compare the Strings in a separate ArrayList to the ones in an objects' attributes. The problem is- the get method isn't working. Every time I try to use .get().getColors();, it tells me that that method doesn't exist.

For context, these are the main objects/ArrayLists:

```
//fav colors of the two people
ArrayList list1 = new ArrayList();
list1.add("RED");
list1.add("BLUE");
list1.add("GREEN");
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.add("YELLOW");
list2.add("PURPLE");

//colors i will compare the people's fav colors to
ArrayList comparison = new ArrayList();
comparison.add("PURPLE");
comparison.add("RED");

Person p1 = new Person("Sarah", 45, list1);
Person p2 = new Person("Simone", 33, list2);

//ArrayList containing the people
ArrayList bioBook = new ArrayList();
bioBook.add(p1);
bioBook.add(p2);
```

These are the attributes of the Person class as well as the get method:

```
private String name;
private int age;
private ArrayList favColors;

public ArrayList getColors(){
     return favColors;
}
```

And this is what I tried to do. I had the thought of storing the favorite colors of that specific person into another ArrayList so I could compare them. It feels like I'm complicating it, and it tells me specifically that bioBook.get(h).getColors().size() and bioBook.get(h).getColors(g) can't work due to the .getColors() method.

```
ArrayList trySmthg = new ArrayList();

//loops through the first ArrayList
    for(int h = 0; h < bioBook.size(); h++){
          //this loops through the ingredients ArrayList of the object
          for(int g = 0; g < bioBook.get(h).getColors().size(); g++){
            tryingSmthg.add(bioBook.get(h).getColors(g));
          }

//this is where i would then compare the two ArrayLists and store how different they are from each other for later use
     
        }
```

I apologize if this is muddled- this is my first time posting here, and I've tried searching on guides to this, but found nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified the type of your lists, therefore they're inferred as a list of generic objects (`List<Object>`), not a list of people (`List<Person>`). Therefore the compiler doesn't know that any element you retrieve with `get()` is a `Person`, hence the `getColors()` method not being shown.

You should be declaring your lists with their generic type parameters like this:

```
List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

The right hand side of this assignment can also be simplified to `new ArrayList<>()`.

---

Most modern IDEs will tell you this so unless yours doesn't, you should make sure to pay attention to compiler warnings. They can generally catch a lot of bugs before they occur.

Answer (score 0):

Java sees ArrayList members as objects by default. You can either type cast them to the Person object, or define the type of object going into the ArrayList.

To specify an array list of the `Person` class:

```
ArrayList<Person> bioBook = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Or alternatively, when you pull an object out of the ArrayList, type cast it to a person:

```
Person person = (Person)(bioBook.get(h));
person.getColors(g);
```

Answer (score -1):

try switching to the following:

```
ArrayList<Object> trySmthg = new ArrayList();

//loops through the first ArrayList
for(int h = 0; h < bioBook.getColors().size(); h++){ // get the fields where you have the 
                                                     //arrayList of arraList
    
          for(int g = 0; g < bioBook.getColors().get(h).size(); g++){
            tryingSmthg.add(bioBook.getColors().get(h).get(g));
          }  
}
```

Comment: Not only is this a very poor way to loop through an `ArrayList`, you also have not defined a type for the `List`. Furthermore, this does not answer any of the questions the OP asked about.

Comment: basically the question is related by getColors method why is no working,  I focus in that

Answer (score -1):

Your array list does not have a type.
For example if I have:
ArrayList persons = new ArrayList<>()
I will be able to do persons.get(1).getName()

Comment: Have you actually tried that? You don't define a type in your code either...